# How i can modify the Search Result fields for our "PnP - search results" web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, pnp-search-webparts

I have a custom list named Contacts which contain 4 fields as follow:-

1. First Name.
2. Last Name
3. Email
4. Customer Name

And I added a "PnP-Search Results" web part + "PnP-Search Box" web part, as follow:-

[image]

where i will get the following fields inside my Search results:-

- Title
- Created
- Summary.

But how i can modified my Search results' fields to show the following fields instead:-

- First Name
- Last Name
- Email
- Customer Name?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure those columns are mapped to managed property first.

Then edit the **Manage columns** setting under layout options of the web part.
(allows you to build you own table view by adding or removing columns dynamically)

[image]

[image]

Then save it to check the result:

[image]

More information for your reference:

https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/usage/search-results/layouts/#details-list

Comment: ok thanks but in my case the "Column Value" drop down inside the "Manage columns" section will not show any results... and if i manually type the managed property value nothing will be shown inside the web part.. any idea?

Comment: Make sure you can use managed property as normal, if you can't,I suggest you open a ticket from Microsoft to check if there is something wrong on back-end side.

Comment: If you are a Site Collection Administrator you can edit your Search Schema at the site collection level and map your fields to Managed Properties. This might help https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/scenarios/set-up-managed-properties/